# How to highlight text in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, quasar

Vue and Quasar frameworks

String:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet CONSECTETUR adipiscing elit"

Template

The following code does not work

```
<span:class="[highlight]">
{{ highlightSearchExpression(string) }}
 />
```

Using v-html (works inconsistently; merge search word with other words)

```
<span
  v-html="highlightSearchExpression(string)"
  :class="[highlight]"
/>
```

Method

```
highlightSearchExpression: function (str) {
  let searchWords = 'CONSECTETUR';

  if (str && searchWords) {
    //In case the search expression contains multiple words
    let searchValues = searchWords.toLowerCase().trim().split(" ");

    let pattern = new RegExp(`(.)(${searchValues.join("|")})`, "gi");
    let replacement = '$1<span class="highlight">$2</span class="highlight">';

    return str.replace(pattern, replacement);

  } else {
    return str;
  }
}
```

CSS

```
.highlight {
  color: #000000;
}
```

PROBLEM TO SOLVE:

Expected

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet **CONSECTETUR** adipiscing elit

Returned

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet**CONSECTETUR**adipiscing elit

**Solution**: In case anyone has the same problem:

First of all remember that I'm using Vue and Quasar.

The problem was in the use of 'row' which somehow interfered with the correct display of the span.

In my actual case:

```
<span
    class="text-grey-10 justify-center row"
    v-html="highlightSearchExpression(string)"
    :class="[highlight]"
 />
```

I changed to the following which works fine:

```
<div class="justify-center row">
    <span
      "class="text-grey-10"
       v-html="highlightSearchExpression(string)"
       :class="[highlight]"
     />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the resulting HTML? Not just what is rendered. It's not easy to tell whether there's whitespace that's being ignored or not.

Comment: It should be `color: #000000;`, not `color: $000000;`. Also `</span class="highlight">` is invalid - a closing tag doesn't have to repeat all the attributes.

Comment: Thanks phuzi and Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to work. See snippet below! There must be something else going on.

```js
const str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet CONSECTETUR adipiscing elit";

const highlightSearchExpression = function (str) {
      let searchWords = 'CONSECTETUR';
    
      if (str && searchWords) {
        //In case the search expression contains multiple words
        let searchValues = searchWords.toLowerCase().trim().split(" ");
    
        let pattern = new RegExp(`(.)(${searchValues.join("|")})`, "gi");
        let replacement = '$1<span class="highlight">$2</span class="highlight">';
    
        return str.replace(pattern, replacement);
    
      } else {
        return str;
      }
    }

document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = highlightSearchExpression(str);
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: $000000;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks phuzi. It must be some detail in Vue or Quasar that I haven't figured out yet.

Comment: @jose Feel free to do some more debugging and ask another question if you get stuck again.

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet works like a charm, just try to replace

```css
.highlight {
  color: $000000;
}
```

by

```css
.highlight {
  color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. the color was a mere lapse in the example. sorry. Correction made.